# Suggestions on how to approach the following inetgral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( x^2 - (x_0 + y)^2 \right)^{2}}{\delta x_0^2 x^2 + \left(x^2 - (x_0 + y)^2 \right)^2} e^{-y/y_0} \ {\rm{d}}y$$

All my attempts so far are fairly elementary manipulations and just using integration by parts. I'm not having much success.

Can anyone suggest an approach, or some integral identities/theorems that might help?

Comment: What is $\delta x_0^2$? Is it a constant $\neq x_0^2$?

Comment: Is the extra square intentionally missing from the denominator or is it supposed to match what's in the numerator exactly?

Comment: @SameerBaheti yes exactly it is a constant different to $x_{0}^2$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Very nice spot, yes there should be power of $2$, I have corrected my question.

Comment: Are you aware that $\int \frac{e^x}{x}=Ei(x)$? Where Ei(x) = exponential integral. Given the form of equation you have you should be able to reduce the rational components using partial fraction decomposition and then reduce the integral into additive components of $e^{-y}/(y+a)$ or $e^{-y}/(y^2+ay+b)$ which also have solutions involving the exponential integral per wolfram alpha. Also note that Ei(-inf) = 0.

Answer (score 1):

By polynomial division:
$$\frac{(x^2-(x_0+y)^2)^2}{\delta x_0^2x^2+(x^2-(x_0+y)^2)^2} = 1 - \frac{\delta x_0^2x^2}{\delta x_0^2x^2+(x^2-(x_0+y)^2)^2}$$

And hence the original integral is transformed into:
$$\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-y/y_0}dy\right) - \left(\delta x_0^2x^2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-y/y_0}}{\delta x_0^2x^2+(x^2-(x_0+y)^2)^2}dy\right) $$

Focusing on the rightmost integral, let $ w=x_0+y $ and hence:

$$\int_{x_0}^\infty\frac{e^{-(w-x_0)/y_0}}{\delta x_0^2x^2+(x^2-w^2)^2}dw$$

Bring out the multiplicative constant from the exponential term:
$$e^{x_0/y_0}\int_{x_0}^\infty\frac{e^{-w/y_0}}{\delta x_0^2x^2+(x^2-w^2)^2}dw$$

Now there is 4th degree polynomial on the denominator which will have four complex roots. By partial fraction decomposition, this integral can be broken down into four terms of the form:
$$ I= \int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{e^{-w/y_0}}{x+a}dw$$

I presume that $\delta>0$ and hence $a$ is necessarily complex.

The indefinite integral of the preceding definite integral is:

$$ e^{a/y_0}Ei\left(-\frac{x+a}{b}\right)$$

Where Ei(x) is the exponential integral.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the exponential integral identity so that is especially useful. So you are saying, in total I will have a five term integral, one from the trivial term you show in the second line and then four for each of the complex roots. And it's then just a linear combination of these integrals?

Comment: Yup! That's correct.

Comment: Thanks! let me play around myself, and then I will gladly accept the answer.